# how to connect vectornav VN-200 to rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have a problem to display imu/data to rviz using catkin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358182/how-to-connect-vectornav-vn-200--to-rviz-?/) by [wathab](https://answers.ros.org/users/57014/wathab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RVIZ is a data visualizer. You need to find a ROS driver to connect to your IMU to broadcast the imu topic. Then RVIZ can subscribe to it for visualization.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wathab](https://answers.ros.org/users/57014/wathab/) on 2020-08-01**:
i get this error when use https://github.com/dawonn/vectornav.git

[ INFO] [1596271819.570015399]: Connecting to : /dev/ttyUSB0 @ 9600 Baud
[ INFO] [1596271819.570177551]: Connecting with default at 9600
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'vn::invalid_operation'
what():  invalid operation
[vectornav-2] process has died [pid 6392, exit code -6, cmd /home/tpc/imu_catkin_ws/devel/lib/vectornav/vnpub __name:=vectornav __log:=/home/tpc/.ros/log/06c8bbcc-d3d4-11ea-985e-606c666e082f/vectornav-2.log].
log file: /home/tpc/.ros/log/06c8bbcc-d3d4-11ea-985e-606c666e082f/vectornav-2*.log